# Arduino Mega different SPI Pins

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, spi

I am working on a project that uses Arduino and Water Level Sensor MS5540C sensor that uses SPI to communicate with Arduino.

When I use Arduino UNO, it was working like a charm using pins 11, 12 and 13, and pin 9 as clock.

Then When I switched to Arduino MEGA, I changed SPI pins to 51, 50 and 52, and I can't get right reads input from the sensor.

Is there any tricks that should be used when switching between Arduino UNO and MEGA ?

Here's the code I use.

Thanks.

```
#include <SPI.h>
int clock = 9;

void resetsensor() //this function keeps the sketch a little shorter
{
 SPI.setDataMode(SPI_MODE0); 
 SPI.transfer(0x15);
 SPI.transfer(0x55);
 SPI.transfer(0x40);
}

void setup() {
 Serial.begin(9600);
 SPI.begin(); //see SPI library details on arduino.cc for details
 SPI.setBitOrder(MSBFIRST);
 SPI.setClockDivider(SPI_CLOCK_DIV32); //divide 16 MHz to communicate on 500 kHz
 pinMode(clock, OUTPUT);
 delay(100);
}

void loop() 
{
 TCCR1B = (TCCR1B & 0xF8) | 1 ; //generates the MCKL signal
 analogWrite (clock, 128) ; 

 resetsensor();//resets the sensor - caution: afterwards mode = SPI_MODE0!

 //Calibration word 1
 unsigned int word1 = 0;
 unsigned int word11 = 0;
 SPI.transfer(0x1D); //send first byte of command to get calibration word 1
 SPI.transfer(0x50); //send second byte of command to get calibration word 1
 SPI.setDataMode(SPI_MODE1); //change mode in order to listen
 word1 = SPI.transfer(0x00); //send dummy byte to read first byte of word
 word1 = word1 << 8; //shift returned byte 
 word11 = SPI.transfer(0x00); //send dummy byte to read second byte of word
 word1 = word1 | word11; //combine first and second byte of word

 resetsensor();//resets the sensor

 //Calibration word 2; see comments on calibration word 1
 unsigned int word2 = 0;
 byte word22 = 0; 
 SPI.transfer(0x1D);
 SPI.transfer(0x60);
 SPI.setDataMode(SPI_MODE1); 
 word2 = SPI.transfer(0x00);
 word2 = word2 <<8;
 word22 = SPI.transfer(0x00);
 word2 = word2 | word22;

 resetsensor();//resets the sensor

 //Calibration word 3; see comments on calibration word 1
 unsigned int word3 = 0;
 byte word33 = 0;
 SPI.transfer(0x1D);
 SPI.transfer(0x90); 
 SPI.setDataMode(SPI_MODE1); 
 word3 = SPI.transfer(0x00);
 word3 = word3 <<8;
 word33 = SPI.transfer(0x00);
 word3 = word3 | word33;

 resetsensor();//resets the sensor

 //Calibration word 4; see comments on calibration word 1
 unsigned int word4 = 0;
 byte word44 = 0;
 SPI.transfer(0x1D);
 SPI.transfer(0xA0);
 SPI.setDataMode(SPI_MODE1); 
 word4 = SPI.transfer(0x00);
 word4 = word4 <<8;
 word44 = SPI.transfer(0x00);
 word4 = word4 | word44;

 long c1 = word1 >> 1;
 long c2 = ((word3 & 0x3F) << 6) | ((word4 & 0x3F));
 long c3 = (word4 >> 6) ;
 long c4 = (word3 >> 6);
 long c5 = (word2 >> 6) | ((word1 & 0x1) << 10);
 long c6 = word2 & 0x3F;

 resetsensor();//resets the sensor

//Temperature:
 unsigned int tempMSB = 0; //first byte of value
 unsigned int tempLSB = 0; //last byte of value
 unsigned int D2 = 0;
 SPI.transfer(0x0F); //send first byte of command to get temperature value
 SPI.transfer(0x20); //send second byte of command to get temperature value
 delay(35); //wait for conversion end
 SPI.setDataMode(SPI_MODE1); //change mode in order to listen
 tempMSB = SPI.transfer(0x00); //send dummy byte to read first byte of value
 tempMSB = tempMSB << 8; //shift first byte
 tempLSB = SPI.transfer(0x00); //send dummy byte to read second byte of value
 D2 = tempMSB | tempLSB; //combine first and second byte of value

 resetsensor();//resets the sensor

 //Pressure:
 unsigned int presMSB = 0; //first byte of value
 unsigned int presLSB =0; //last byte of value
 unsigned int D1 = 0;
 SPI.transfer(0x0F); //send first byte of command to get pressure value
 SPI.transfer(0x40); //send second byte of command to get pressure value
 delay(35); //wait for conversion end
 SPI.setDataMode(SPI_MODE1); //change mode in order to listen
 presMSB = SPI.transfer(0x00); //send dummy byte to read first byte of value
 presMSB = presMSB << 8; //shift first byte
 presLSB = SPI.transfer(0x00); //send dummy byte to read second byte of value
 D1 = presMSB | presLSB; 

 const long UT1 = (c5 * 8) + 20224;
 const long dT =(D2 - UT1);
 const long TEMP = 200 + ((dT * (c6 + 50))/1024);
 const long OFF  = (c2*4) + (((c4 - 512) * dT)/4096);
 const long SENS = c1 + ((c3 * dT)/1024) + 24576;

 long PCOMP = ((((SENS * (D1 - 7168))/16384)- OFF)/32)+250;
 float TEMPREAL = TEMP/10;
 Serial.print("pressure =    ");
 Serial.print(PCOMP);
 Serial.println(" mbar"); 

 const long dT2 = dT - ((dT >> 7 * dT >> 7) >> 3);
 const float TEMPCOMP = (200 + (dT2*(c6+100) >>11))/10;
 Serial.print("temperature = ");
 Serial.print(TEMPCOMP);  
 Serial.println(" °C");
 Serial.println("************************************");

 delay(300);
 }
```

Comment: Transferring Pin 9 to 12 truly works. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was basically because some limitations in Arduino MEGA,
You can't use `pin 9`, instead use `pin 12`.

It works like a charm.

Thanks.